# Call class constructor to emulate polymorphism in javascript

Tags: javascript, polymorphism

This is probably a duplicate, but I didn't find anything.

Basically I have this (over-simplified) code:

```
class A {
  doSomething() {
    return new A();
  }
}

class B extends A {
  doSomething() {
    return new B();
  }
}

const a = new A().doSomething() // a should be an instance of A
const b = new B().doSomething() // b should be an instance of B
```

Here, `doSomething` does exactly the same thing in both classes, except for the type of the instance returned (I'm trying to have immutable instances).

So what I did was to modify the code as follows:

```
class A {
  doSomething() {
    return this.constructor();
  }
}

class B extends A {
  // nothing
}
```

... which seems to work fine. But I get a feeling this is more of a hack than anything.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Is `return this.constructor();` supposed to be `return new this.constructor()`? Maybe look into using `Reflect.construct`

Comment: Well I did omit the `new` since that didn't seem to have an impact here, but then again I'm really experimenting here. As I understand from a quick look at MDN, Reflect.construct is just a function-like way of calling "new [something]". Here I'm trying to call a class name without knowing what it is (since it can be either the parent of child's class)

Comment: Well, nevermind that, having `new` was needed so I'll add this, at least!